# Replace and remove items from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, formatting

I want to replace my_string

```
my_string = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.05], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 441.0], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.9625]]'
```

such that it gives result like this

```
my_string = '4.6x4.3x4.3 8.75x5.6x6.6 4.6x4.3x4.3'

last_item = '85.05 441.0 85.9625'
```

The last items in the list has no fixed length
For the first objective I've written

```
mystring = mystring.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(", ","x")
```

But I need a more pythonic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this if `my_string = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.05], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 441.0], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.9625]]'`:

```
import ast
my_string = " ".join(["x".join([str(k) for k in i[:-1]]) for i in ast.literal_eval(my_string)])
last_item = " ".join([str(k[-1]) for k in ast.literal_eval(my_string)])
```

**UPDATE** :

In your question, `my_string = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.05], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 441.0] [4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.9625]]'`. If you intend to use this as `my_string`, then try this :

```
my_string = " ".join(["x".join([str(k) for k in i[:-1]]) for i in [i.replace(",","").split() for i in my_string.replace("[","").split("]") if len(i) >1]])
last_item = " ".join([str(k[-1]) for k in [i.replace(",","").split() for i in my_string.replace("[","").split("]") if len(i) >1
```

In the second case, we first do `my_string.replace("[","")` which results in `'4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.05], 8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 441.0] 4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.9625]]'`. Now we split them with `.split("]")` which results into `['4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.05', ', 8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 441.0', ' 4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.9625', '', '']`. We need to remove the items here which are just vacant string, so we incorporate `if len(i) >1` part in the list comprehension. Now we get `['4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.05', ', 8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 441.0', ' 4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.9625']`. We need to remove the commas in the string items of the list. So for each item in this list we do `.replace(",","")` and then followed by `.split()` which now results in `[['4.6', '4.3', '4.3', '85.05'], ['8.75', '5.6', '6.6', '441.0'], ['4.6', '4.3', '4.3', '85.9625']]`. Now for each sublist, we take items upto the last one and we do `"x".join()` and assign to `my_string`. Taking that list we can add all the last items with `" ".join()` and assign that to `last_item` variable.

Comment: I tried running your code but it gives this error : 
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Subscript object at 0x000001D7762AFFD0>

Comment: Updated with info, check !

Comment: Sorry! but could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @RahulSharma Check now !

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dict`

```
my_string = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.05], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 441.0], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3,` 85.9625]]'

    b = {'[': '', ']': '', ',': 'x'}
    for x, y in b.items():
        my_string = my_string.replace(x, y)
    print(my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string looks like valid json string. Maybe like this:

```
import json
def to_str(lst):
    return 'x'.join([str(e) for e in lst])
my_string = '[[4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.05], [8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 441.0], [4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 85.9625]]'
temp = json.loads(my_string)
first_items = ' '.join([to_str(x[:-1]) for x in temp])
last_items = ' '.join([str(x[-1]) for x in temp])
print(first_items)
print(last_items)
```